# Programmatically create libraries folder under Roaming profile for new users, as first desktop login does

Tags: windows, impersonation, user-accounts, roaming-profile

I'm creating some new windows users and assigning admin rights with

```
net UserName Password /add
net localgroup administrators UserName /add
```

After this point, the user is created, but it's not really loaded. As for example, the `C:\Users\UserName` folder hasn't been created yet.

After that, I run some processes impersonating the user by using

```
psexec -i -h -u UserName -p Password process.exe
```

After this, some additional things are loaded for the user, I can see it on  `C:\Users\UserName`, and on the system registry, but it's still missing part of the roaming profile.

In particular, I'm looking at the folder `C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\libraries` not being created (Note: this is true only for win10, in win7 it does get created). This folder seems to be created only when logging with the user through the desktop login.

How can I finish initializing the user so that the user is loaded the same way that logging through the desktop would do it (or at least so that `C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\libraries` is created).

I've tried using `LoadUserProfile` but I haven't had any luck so far

```
            IntPtr hUser = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                bool result = LogonUser(
                    userName, null, password,
                    LOGON_TYPE.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
                    LOGON_PROVIDER.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                    out hUser);
                if (result == false)
                {
                    Exception ex = new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(
                        Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    throw ex;
                }

                PROFILEINFO profileInfo = new PROFILEINFO();
                profileInfo.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(profileInfo);
                profileInfo.lpUserName = Environment.MachineName+ @"\" + userName;
                result = LoadUserProfile(
                    hUser, ref profileInfo);

                if (result == false)
                {
                    Exception ex = new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(
                        Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (hUser != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(hUser);
                }
            }
```

Any solution on C#, powershell, or batch scripting would do it.